# How to set custom validator manually in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I would like to set my custom validator "validateName" manually in my component to *true* in order to show the following error message:

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="nameControl.hasError('validateName')">Name not found.</mat-error>
```

The user should type in a name and click a button. After this, the name(input) is validated in the background. When name is not found the error message needs to be shown.

Is there a way to achieve this? Unfortunately I haven't found any solution.

Comment: Have you written the custom validator method?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Can you give some details?

Comment: Where is that `validateName ` from? Is that error from some validator method/function you have written?

Comment: yes, but I want to to call the method only when the button is clicked.

Comment: if you want to run a custom validator on click then id just do it in the function fired submitting, then show the mat-error with this conditional. if you wanted to be built into a reactive form you need a custom validator like @wentjun mentioned. It sounds like you want it on click, id go with the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to include another condition for your `*ngIf` at your component.html:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="yourForm.controls['nameControl'].hasError('validateName') && isSubmitted">Name not found.</mat-error>

<button (click)="submitForm">submit</button>
```

And on your component.ts, when the button is clicked, the `submitForm` method will be fired, which will switch `isSubmitted` to true, if `validateName` error is present.

```
isSubmitted: boolean = false;
.
.
submitForm() {
  if (this.yourForm.controls['nameControl'].hasError('validateName')) {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
  } else {
    // handle the rest if no error;
  }
}
```